# Dimensionless numbers plots

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I've used the  `Buckingham Pi Theorem` in an electric water heater to find the relationship of the generated heat with other physical quantities.

> Parameters:
> \begin{align*}
> Q & = \text{Heat} \\
> \dot{m} & = \text{Mass flow} \\
> \Delta T & = \text{Temperature variation} \\
> c & = \text{Specific heat capacity (of water)} \\
> V & = \text{Voltage} \\
> I & = \text{Current} \\
> R & = \text{Electrical resistance} \\
> t & = \text{Time} \\
> \end{align*}
>
> Heat as a function of all the parameters:
> \begin{equation}
> Q = f \left(\dot{m},\ \Delta T,\ c,\ V,\ I,\ R,\ t\right)
> \label{eq: ecuación a resolver propuesta}
> \end{equation}
>
> $\Pi$s:
> \begin{align*}
> \Pi_1 & = \dfrac{Q}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^2}  \\
> \Pi_2 & = \dfrac{R\ I^2}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7} \\
> \Pi_3 & = \ \dfrac{V\ I}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7}
> \end{align*}
>
> Relationship between the $\Pi$s:
> \begin{equation}
> \Pi_1 = f\left(\Pi_2,\ \Pi_3\right)
> \end{equation}
> $$ \dfrac{Q}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^2} = f\left(\dfrac{R\ I^2}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7},\ \dfrac{V\ I}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7}\right) $$
> \begin{equation}
> Q = \dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^2 \cdot f\left(\dfrac{R\ I^2}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7},\ \dfrac{V\ I}{\dot{m}\ \Delta T\ c\ t^7}\right)
> \end{equation}

Now, my doubt is how I can plot the last equation in terms of the $\Pi$s and the plot for $Q$. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the goal of your dimensional analysis; why the choice of those variables? To me the power draw $P$ would be a more natural choice then $V$, $I$ or $R$. Clearly they are related by the equations, $V=IR$, $P=IV=I^2R$ so your $\Pi_2$ and $\Pi_3$ are actually the same variable. Furthermore, the dependence of $t^7$ seems unphysical to me but perhaps that is due to your choice in variables.

Comment: I was worried about the $t^7$ term too, but the algebra for the $\Pi$s is consistent. I will try to do the math with $P$ to get less terms. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from my comment to your post.

To generate a plot like that they calculate $\pi_1$ (y-axis) as function of $\pi_2$ (x-axis) with $\pi_3$ as a parameter in the range $[0,1]$.

In essence they get a parameterized equation $y=x+\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+\alpha^2\right)$ with $y=\pi_1$, $x=\pi_2$ and $\alpha=\pi_3$ which is an inverted parabola with symmetry about $x=1$.

To plot your equations, you will have to set your water heater to different values of $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ and measure the value for $\pi_1$. You can then plot the points on a graph and perhaps you get an idea of the funtional form of the equations.